# Cron job for 'on click' jquery command through a html button

Tags: jquery, cron, onclick, buttonclick

Hello I want to program a daily click.
It is a WP plugin which I want to run on auto.
¿Can this be done with cron job?

The script take a snapshot of the site and then saves it as a sub folder on the web page.

jquery

```
/**
* create new
*/
$('#snapshot-plugin #create-snapshot').on('click', function() {
$errorOutput.hide();
var data = {
  name: $('#snapshot-name').val(),
  action: 'add_snapshot'
}

if(data.name.length === 0) {
  $errorOutput.text('Snapshot name is required');
  $errorOutput.show();
  return;
}

if(data.name.length > 200) {
  $errorOutput.text('Snapshot name is too long!');
  $errorOutput.show();
  return;
}

$('#snapshot-plugin .loader-inner.ball-grid-pulse').css('display', 'inline');

$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'admin-ajax.php',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response); 
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  var snapshot = response.snapshot;
  var rowId = 'snapshot-' + snapshot.name;

  $('#template-row').clone().prop('id', rowId).appendTo('#available-snapshots > table').show();
  $('#' + rowId + ' td:nth-child(1)').html(snapshot.id);
  $('#' + rowId + ' td:nth-child(2)').html(snapshot.name);
  $('#' + rowId + ' td:nth-child(3)').html(snapshot.creationDate.split(' ')[0]);
  $('#' + rowId + ' td:nth-child(4) a').prop('href', response.snapshot_url).on('click', delete_snapshot);
  $('#' + rowId + ' td:nth-child(5) a').prop('id', 'delete-snapshot-' + snapshot.name).on('click', delete_snapshot);

  $('#available-snapshots').show();

}).fail(function(response) {
  console.log(response);

  $errorOutput.text(response.responseJSON.message);
  $errorOutput.show();

}).always(function(response) {
  $loader.hide();
});
});
```

html

```
  <div id="snapshot-plugin">
<div class="container clearfix"><div class="title">
  <h1>Snapshot Manager</h1>
  <br>
  <h2>Create new snapshot</h2>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="snapshot-name" type="text" placeholder="unique name" value="<?php setlocale(LC_ALL,'es_MX.UTF-8'); date_default_timezone_set ('America/Merida'); echo strftime('%d-%b-%Y~%H:%M:%S'); ?>">
    <input type="button" id="create-snapshot" class="btn" value="Create">
  </div>
    <div class="loader-inner ball-grid-pulse">
      <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div> 
  <div class="output-group">
    <span class="output error"></span>
  </div>
```

Produces a static snapshot of your site.
Files are renamed with the correct extension if they come from a CDN.
All links produced are relative – they won’t redirect to the original website but to the other static files.

This plugin is a wrapper for the Linux/Unix wget application. Your server must use Linux/Unix!

Tks.

Comment: use a serverside library, for example `wkhtmltopdf` to convert your html to an image, u can this with a shell command / cron

Comment: Tks for answering... `wkhtmltopdf` is a very cool feature to have in consideration, yet in this case the script is using `wget` to create the snapshot, which is working perfect... `
  $wget_command = 'wget ';
  $wget_command .= '--mirror ';
  $wget_command .= '--directory-prefix=' . get_home_path() . 'output ';
  ` I am just looking for a way to "cron" the jquery click which is performed at the frontend by the user. Please advise.